# How to set cookie with Http-request in VBA?

Tags: vba, cookies, web-scraping, httprequest, yahoo-finance

Since a few days Yahoo Finance partially doesn´t support Internet Explorer 11.

My webscraping macro no longer works since the approriate links to retreive the csv-files aren´t visible in IE11. They are still present if I check the html source code with other browsers.

I want to use an http-request to get the data but once the request has been sent an error returns instead of a csv-file. I think I get the error message because I didn´t set a cookie.

I found several posts to this theme here but I didn´t understand the code and I´m not really familiar with how cookies work.

What I understood is that the cookie has been set before the Http-request departs but I do not know how to do so.

So the first thing I´d like to ensure is whether it is possible to do both things with one http-request, set a cookie and retrieve the csv-file.

The code I wrote:

```
Sub HttpRequest()

' Create Http Request

Dim xml As Object

Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

xml.Open "Get", "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/DAI.DE?period1=1403474400& _
period2=1561240800&interval=1d&events=div&crumb=43WnmWAcccz", False

xml.send

' save as textfile

Dim fs, a
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("E:\daimler.txt", True)
    a.WriteLine (xml.responseText)
    a.Close

End Sub
```

This is the error I get:

> ```
> {
>     "finance": {
>         "error": {
>             "code": "Unauthorized",
>             "description": "Invalid cookie"
>         }
>     } }
> ```